# Regex not matching \t\n\r\f\v in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of a strings:

```
content = ['***************************************\n\t', 'ADVENTURE', '*', 'Solving', 'it', 'in', 'easy', 'steps', '*\n\t', '*\t\t\t\t', '*\n\t', '*\t\t\t\t', '*\n\t', '***************************************\n\t\t', 'FROM:', 'THE', 'ROM', 'DR.', 'CALL', 'HER']
```

In which I'm trying to remove anything that ends with a non-alphanumeric character like \t \n \v and so on.

I have the following code:

```
import re

for each in content:
m = re.match('.*[\t\n\r\f\v]+',each) 
if m:
    content.remove(each)
```

But the output is still giving me strings with \n or \t. Any ideas?

Comment: Change [\t\n\r\f\v] into \s

Comment: Do you want to preserve the order of items in content?

Comment: Yes I do @Thomasleveil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that `content` list is getting dynamically updated. This creates the following problem. Suppose it picks 8th indexed item i.e., `'*\n\t'`, this matches regex and gets removed which makes `'*\t\t\t\t'` to move one position backward and the next item picked is `'*\n\t'`.Thus `'*\t\t\t\t'` remains in the `content` list. To avoid this thing you need to use `copy` module as:

```
>>> import copy
>>> content = ['***************************************\n\t', 'ADVENTURE', '*', 'Solving', 'it', 'in', 'easy', 'steps', '*\n\t', '*\t\t\t\t', '*\n\t', '*\t\t\t\t', '*\n\t', '***************************************\n\t\t', 'FROM:', 'THE', 'ROM', 'DR.', 'CALL', 'HER']
>>> for i in copy.copy(content):
...     m=re.match(r'.*[\t\n\r\f\v]+',i)
...     if m:
...        content.remove(i)
... 
>>> content
['ADVENTURE', '*', 'Solving', 'it', 'in', 'easy', 'steps', 'FROM:', 'THE', 'ROM', 'DR.', 'CALL', 'HER']
```

You can also do it without using `copy` module as:

```
>>> for i in content[:]:
...     m=re.match(r'.*[\t\n\r\f\v]+',i)
...     if m:
...        content.remove(i)
... 
>>> content
['ADVENTURE', '*', 'Solving', 'it', 'in', 'easy', 'steps', 'FROM:', 'THE', 'ROM', 'DR.', 'CALL', 'HER']
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. I forgot about the list being updated..... major derp momeny on my part. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You dont need `regex` , use `str.strip()` and `set` (**if you have not duplicated elements in your list (or you dont want duplicates) because `set` remove duplicates** ), first you `strip` all the element of `content` list (removing whitspaces at leading and trailing of the string ) and then use a logic and `&` that works between tow `set` between new striped list and first list to chose elements that are in both (elements that `strip()` function doesn't change them so those are in both list) :

```
>>> new=[i.strip() for i in content]
>>> set(content) & set(new) 
set(['*', 'in', 'ROM', 'HER', 'Solving', 'it', 'CALL', 'ADVENTURE', 'easy', 'DR.', 'steps', 'THE', 'FROM:'])
```

Comment: Is set required here?

Comment: @Vimal yes you need it for logic and

Comment: No. I don't think the set is required, because he just wanted to remove \n or \t or \v if I understand his question correctly. But I like your answer.

Comment: @Vimal yep , you are right , and as i don't seen any duplicated element in his list i, use `set` anyway i edited the answer ! , thanks for reminding and your attention too ! ;)

Comment: I have dups and I need to keep the dubs + the order is important.

Answer (score 0):

Just print the strings which ends with alphanumeric instead of removing the ones which ends with the chars which isn't alphanumeric.

```
>>> content = ['***************************************\n\t', 'ADVENTURE', '*', 'Solving', 'it', 'in', 'easy', 'steps', '*\n\t', '*\t\t\t\t', '*\n\t', '*\t\t\t\t', '*\n\t', '***************************************\n\t\t', 'FROM:', 'THE', 'ROM', 'DR.', 'CALL', 'HER']
>>> for i in content:
    if re.search(r'(?s).*[A-Za-z0-9]$', i):
        print(i)


ADVENTURE
Solving
it
in
easy
steps
THE
ROM
CALL
HER
```

Through list_comprehension.

```
>>> [i for i in content if re.search(r'(?s).*[A-Za-z0-9]$', i)]
['ADVENTURE', 'Solving', 'it', 'in', 'easy', 'steps', 'THE', 'ROM', 'CALL', 'HER']
```

`(?s)` in the above regex is called DOTALL modifier which makes dot in the regex to match even line breaks.

**OR**

```
>>> [i for i in content if not re.search(r'(?s).*[\t\n\r\f\v]+$', i)]
['ADVENTURE', '*', 'Solving', 'it', 'in', 'easy', 'steps', 'FROM:', 'THE', 'ROM', 'DR.', 'CALL', 'HER']
```